# VisualStudio does not compile projects with targets that miss output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a common msbuild file that is imported in all our project files. In this common file I have defined a target and specified it's inputs (the project file itself) and outputs (a file generated from contents of the project file):

```
  <Target Name="Generate" 
    Inputs="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" 
    Outputs="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).xyz">
    <Exec Command="..."/>
  </Target>
```

When I compile a single project everything works fine for that project: If the output file does not exist it is created. If it exists and is newer than the project file the target does not run.

My problem is that the projects this project depends on are not build even if their respective output files do not exist.

So if I have projects

A, B and C

where C depends on A and B.

Now imagine that A's, B's and C's output is up-to-date except for the *.xyz files which do not exist since I just added the new target.

If I now compile C in VS only project C compiles and C.xyz is created but not A.xyz and B.xyz!

As I understood msbuild and VS must build each project up to the current one if at least one target output for that project is missing or out of date!?

So my question is: what is wrong with my target specification?

Comment: How did you wire up your special target to the build pipeline ? Are you using DependsOn, Before\AfterTargets or overriding existing target ?

Comment: yes, this is close to what I'm going to ask - run your build with /v:diag switch and see which targets are being triggered for your command. I strongly suspect that afterbuild is being called only once for  the entire pipeline, e.g. 'after C Build' only instead of after each rebuild. Pick another target and wire it up there.